# Sensor connectivity

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]
[image]

Dear all, 
as a novice I need some help from somebody with knowledge in electrical engineering. I need to supply a sensor with power, as shown on the left side of the picture. The sensor uses a plug as shown in the right section.
I would like the source to be a battery (standalone solution), can I use a 12V motorcycle battery or do I risk to destroy the sensor for any kind of reason ?
What is the name of this type of plug  ?

Comment: That's one of many versions of a DIN connector.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and doesn't make any sense. What's the make and type of the sensor? What has the left diagram to do with anything if you want to power it with a car battery?

Comment: Anyway, don't guess it's going to work. RS485 devices usually require much lower-voltage power, 12V is too much. It's not unheard of for anyone to go against the common practices, but without more information the chances of this working are slim.

Comment: You do realize the sensor will still have to output it's data to somewhere too, right? What's that device going to be powered by?

Comment: The left diagram gives information about the power source and the +/- connection at the plug. Currently I use a regular transformer 220VAC to 12VDC and it works fine, so 12V is not too much. The sensor output is via ethernet, another plug and therefore not relevant here.

Comment: The transformer you currently use always delivers exactly 12V. A car battery will provide you *at least* 12V. If the sensor has no problem with that, sure, it would work.

Comment: Can please share sensor technical details?

Comment: I added the wiring above the text.

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheet or user manual for your unit.  [Those diagrams came from somewhere.]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided I don't think you will have any issue using a 12V motorcycle battery. Attach below is information on 12V Motorcycle battery current draw which is over 2.5 Ah. The current requirement for you sensor module is 200mA. Therefore you should not have any issues.

[image: 12V Motorcycle Battery Specification]

**References:**

- [Battery Applications and Specifications - Yuasa](http://www.yuasabatteries.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Catalog-2018-Final.x78244.pdf)
- [Tech Tip for Recharging Your Motorcycle Battery the Right Way](https://www.motorcyclecruiser.com/tech-tip-for-recharging-your-motorcycle-battery-right-way)